# Declare Multi Dimensional Array in Package.json

Tags: javascript, npm

In my package file im trying to declare a multi dimensional array:

```
"languages": {
    "en":["au", "uk"],
    "de":["de"]
 }
```

This parses ok, but I'm trying to later loop the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++) {
```

This does nothing as languages.length is undefined. I have logged the languages array and it is the same as the array in the package.json file.

If my array in package.json is incorrect could you let me know and if my way of looping through it is wrong, could you also let me know.

Comment: languages is not an array but an object. Use for-in

Comment: Languages is not an array, it is object, you can't use length property. Try Object.keys(languages).length